# Deleting single line comments in file

Tags: sed

How would I be able to delete single line comments starting with `/*......*/` and

By anywhere I mean it can be in a line by itself or after some equation for example.

I was thinking something along the lines of :

```
s/\/\*.*\*\///g'
```

Comment: does something like `printf "sample comment code: /* your comment */" // edge comment` is to be take into account ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e 's|/\*.*\*/||g'                 => to remove /* ... */
sed -e 's|//.*||g'                     => to remove //...
sed -e 's|/\*.*\*/||g' -e 's|//.*||g'  => to remove both /* ... */ and //...
```

**Example:**

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~$ cat file
jksdjskjdsd /* jdskdskd */
jdskdjsd // ksldksldsdks
uiiu
sdlcb@ubuntu:~$ sed -e 's|/\*.*\*/||g' -e 's|//.*||g' file
jksdjskjdsd 
jdskdjsd 
uiiu
```

Comment: This also removes the `// ksldksldsdks`

Answer (score 2):

Or if you don't like the picket fence look, you can change the separator and also use character classes to prevent having to escape everything:

```
's|/[*].*[*]/||g'
```

Note: allowable separator replacement varies slightly by OS.

Comment: how would you implement this to the "//" comments?

Comment: same way `'s|//.*||g'`  Note - this will remove the `//` **and** the remainder of the line.